# Citing Multiple paragraphs MLA

Tags: syntactic-analysis, citation, dialogue, paragraphs, mla

Had a quick question about how I should cite with multiple paragraphs (MLA).

Here is how the text appears in the source (*The Great Gatsby*):

```
     'An Oxford man!' He was incredulous. 'Like hell he is! He 
wears a pink suit.'

     'Nevertheless he's an Oxford man.'

     'Oxford, New Mexico,' snorted Tom contemptuously, 'or 
something like that'.
```

Would I cite it like this:

... with the following exchange: "'An Oxford man!' He was incredulous. 'Like hell he is! He wears a pink suit'. 'Nevertheless he's an Oxford man'. 'Oxford, New Mexico,' snorted Tom contemptuously, 'or something like that'."

Or would I use a block quotation like this:

... with the following exchange:

```
     'An Oxford man!' He was incredulous. 'Like hell he is! He 
wears a pink suit.'

     'Nevertheless he's an Oxford man.'

     'Oxford, New Mexico,' snorted Tom contemptuously, 'or 
something like that'.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *MLA Handbook* (8th ed.), 1.3.7, says:

> Do not use opening and closing quotation marks to enclose quotations set off from the text, but reproduce any quotation marks that are in the passage quoted.
>
> In "Memories of West Street and Lekpke," Robert Lowell, a conscientious objector (or "C.O."), recounts meeting a Jehovah's Witness in prison:
>
> I was so out of things, I'd never heard
>       of the Jehovah's Witnesses.
>       "Are you a C.O.?" I asked a fellow jailbird.
>       "No," he answered, "I'm a J.W." (36-39)

By "set off from the text," it means a block quote, which has a left-margin indent.

Notice that it uses a block quote for the lines of text, and *then* provides the citation *(36-39)*, which, in this case, is citing line numbers rather than page numbers because ["Memories of West Street and Lekpke"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/48338/memories-of-west-street-and-lepke) is a poem.

---

It does, however, provide a different style where a block quote is *not* used:

> Use double quotation marks around quotations incorporated into the text and single quotation marks around quotations within those quotations.
>
> In "Memories of West Street and Lekpke," Robert Lowell, a conscientious objector (or "C.O.)", recounts meeting a Jehovah's Witness in prison: "'Are you a C.O.?' I asked a fellow jailbird. / 'No, he answered, 'I'm a J.W.'" (38-39)

Notice the difference in quotation marks when no block quote is used, and how a slash (*/*) character indicates a line break in the poem. A stanza break would be indicated by a double slash (*//*).

---

*MLA*, 1.3.3, says this about poetry:

> Verse quotations of more than three lines should be set off from your text as a block.

For quotes of *prose*, *MLA* 1.3.2 says:

> If a quotation extends to more than four lines when run into your text, set it off from the text as a block indented half an inch from the left margin.

I would certainly use a block quote for your example text. If nothing else, it simply looks better.

> In *The Great Gatsby* is the following exchange:
>
> 'An Oxford man!' He was incredulous. 'Like hell he is! He wears a pink suit.'
>        'Nevertheless he's an Oxford man.'
>       'Oxford, New Mexico,' snorted Tom contemptuously, 'or
> something like that'. (50)

The (*50*) I used in that is just an arbitrary page number I made up.